# How can I change status of all the entries in a channel to closed?

Tags: entries, channels, status

I've looked through all the tables, and I can not find a column for status. I'd like to close all entries in channelId X. Is there a way to bulk edit entries via DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab all of the entry IDs you want from the `craft_entries` table, then find the rows matching those IDs in the `craft_elements` table and set their `enabled` column to `0` to disable them en masse.